# OpenGL 4x4 Matrix move object by X-axis

Tags: c++, ios, matrix

I have an object in 2D scene in my iOS app. Position of the object is given by matrix

```
Vect3F translation = Vect3F(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

Matrix44F translationMatrix({
            1, 0, 0, translation[0],
            0, 1, 0, translation[1],
            0, 0, 1, translation[2],
            0, 0, 0, 1
});
```

I need to move the object by X-axis by 10 points. How do I achieve that? I am new to OpenGL.

Comment: Vect3F translation = Vect3F(10.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

Comment: Thanks, I will try that now

Comment: It works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change translation vector. X coordinate is the first. Try this:

```
Vect3F translation = Vect3F(10.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```